# how to get value of textbox in listview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
            <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvAttachments" ItemPlaceholderID="ph" OnItemDataBound="lvAttachments_ItemDataBound">
                <LayoutTemplate>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </LayoutTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnReject" OnClick="btnReject_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbReason" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

My question is: how to get text from textbox, while btnReject click action?

```
protected void btnReject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton btnReject = (LinkButton)sender;
    // how to get tbReason.Text from this item?

}
```

Regards

edit:

Problem resolved !
We just need to add in Page_Load code to prevent re-load listview and clear textboxes:)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1712482.aspx/1

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        lvAttachments.DataSource = tAttachmentBO.getAttachmentsToAccept();
        lvAttachments.DataBind();
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Can u show ur item data bound method code

Comment: Post your solution as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

I'm on ipad so apologize for any mistakes

```
TextBox txt = (TextBox)btnReject.Parent.FindControl("tbReason")
```

Comment: the same problem - when I try to get tb.text - text is null.. just "".. Why? How to resolve it?